# ¿cómo graficar varias columnas (variables) en un mismo gráfico de líneas con ggplot2?

Tags: ggplot2

he intentado graficar varias columnas (variables) pero no logro conseguirlo.
mis datos siguen la siguiente estructura:
Tasa de desempleo por estado
[image: datos]

Me interesa que en el eje x sea para el Periodo, en el eje y sea la tasa (%) y que cada estado se represente en gráfico de líneas de diferentes colores. Nota: 2019/01 indica año/número de trimestre.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.